# ArrayList with a variable number of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need an arrayList that contains a variable number of arrays.

```
        ArrayList <int[]> aa = new ArrayList<int[]> ();
    int b = 1;
    int array [] = new int [5];


    while ( b == 1){

            for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                array [i] = in.nextInt();
            }

        aa.add(array);
        System.out.println("If you want to insert another array, press 1");
        b = in.nextInt();

    }
```

logically this code does not work, because the array is overwritten every time and at the end the output is always the same... how can I solve my Problem? .. :)

Comment: Put the declaration of array inside the loop and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the array length?

Comment: @efekctive. Why does it matter as long as the value is used properly?

Comment: suppose just move the `int array [] = new int[5]` inside  to the while loop and try. think its just for learning.

Comment: It does not affect the code but it does not tell the user that the arrays entered have a constant length of 5. the user can enter 10 ints thinking one array was created but he/she created two

Comment: thank you People!! :) the array length is constant because it was a Test just for learning ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, as you correctly assessed, the contents of a single array get modified, but the same reference is added to your list over and over. If you move the line `int array [] = new int [5];` into your while loop, the a new array will be created within each iteration, and no arrays will be overwritten.